# What is the probability of killing two enemies out of four with two random strikes if you know the damage that you deal and the enemies' hitpoints?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This problem came up in a game I was playing and I was curious how I would apply conditional probability here, or if conditional probability is even appropriate.

---

Problem: Imagine a turn-based game where you are up against four enemies. Their health points are as follows:

- Enemy A: 5
- Enemy B: 8
- Enemy C: 1
- Enemy D: 11

You have an option to play an attack that strikes randomly twice. It may strike the same enemy twice if their health pool allows for it (e.g., striking enemy D twice), or it may strike two different enemies. Each time it strikes, this attack deals 8 points of damage. What is the probability that you kill two enemies?

---

I tried working this out by hand, and here's what I got:

- Kill A: $\frac{3}{4}$ chance; then $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of killing another = ($\frac{3}{4}) \times (\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$
- Kill B: $\frac{3}{4}$ chance; then $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of killing another = ($\frac{3}{4}) \times (\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$
- Kill C: $\frac{3}{4}$ chance; then $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of killing another = ($\frac{3}{4}) \times (\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$
- Kill D: $0$ chance, then $\frac{4}{4}$ for the second strike since all enemies are within killing range = $0 \times \frac{4}{4} = 0$

We can end up in any one of these four states, so summing them, we get: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$ which... makes no sense because it exceeds $1$.

---

I also tried applying Bayes' Theorem, but that didn't get me very far as I had trouble identifying what the two probabilities are:

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}P(B|A)
$$

Where:

- $P(A|B)$ is the probability of killing a second enemy given that you already killed one
- $P(A)$ is the probability of killing an enemy on your second hit
- $P(B)$ is the probability of killing an enemy on your first hit
- $P(B|A)$... doesn't seem to make sense in the context of this problem

Where am I going wrong? Should I not be treating this as a conditional probability problem?

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  If, say, you strike $C$ first, then $C$ is gone (right?)...does that mean you can't strike them again?  If so, then to kill $2$ enemies, you just have to avoid striking $D$.  Or have I misunderstood?  Of course, if you are allowed to uselessly strike at a dead enemy, then you also have to avoid that.

Comment: The probability of killing $A$ on the first hit is 1/4, not 3/4, and similarly for $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, that's correct: If you hit C, then they die and you are left with only three enemies. I was under the impression that this is conditional probability because your candidate pool for the second strike depends on which enemy you hit on the first strike.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Oops, you're right!

Comment: It is very confusing. From where have you got chances of 3/4 each for A,B,C, and 0 for D ? These have been put in the solution, but aren't there in the question !

Comment: @trueblueanil I worked out the math incorrectly. For some reason, I was looking at the whole group and considering the probability of killing one enemy, which is $\frac{3}{4}$, but then I mistakenly applied that probability individually to each enemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I think it's quite simple.
To kill 2 enemies, you cannot hit enemy D. Hence, for the first strike it's $\frac{3}{4}$, and then you need to hit one of the remaining two with less than 8 points of health, i.e. $\frac{2}{3}$. Which gets you to $\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That's the answer I got as well, for the same reasons (+1).  Like you, however, I feel like we are missing some key part of the question.

Comment: Oh... I may have been overthinking this. I thought I would need to use conditional probability here because I was under the impression that the first strike changes the outcome of the second strike (because your enemy pool might change).

Comment: As others mentioned, they way you worked it out is fine, but the probability to strike each one of A,B,C,D is $\frac{1}{4}$ on the first strike. This gets you the same result if you add up the three cases where 2 enemies are killed, but there is no need to distinguish those three, as they are all killed by a single strike.